# How to save complex data as rows with numpy savetxt?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How I can save complex data in this following format?

```
0.0001760855-0.0000927256j
-0.0002311308+0.0000122892j
0.0002447444+0.0000968709j
-0.0002038497-0.0002121365j
0.0001077393+0.0003059170j
0.0000306011-0.0003521998j
-0.0001864669+0.0003330580j
0.0003283114-0.0002435598j
-0.0004244564+0.0000938909j
0.0004501374+0.0000918577j
```

But with numpy.savetxt("path_to_array", array) I have this:

```
(1.760855000000000135e-04+-9.272560000000000546e-05j)
 (-2.311307999999999928e-04+1.228919999999999916e-05j)
 (2.447444000000000008e-04+9.687089999999999438e-05j)
 (-2.038497000000000009e-04+-2.121365000000000110e-04j)
 (1.077393000000000003e-04+3.059170000000000053e-04j)
 (3.060110000000000082e-05+-3.521997999999999817e-04j)
 (-1.864668999999999951e-04+3.330580000000000086e-04j)
 (3.283113999999999954e-04+-2.435597999999999919e-04j)
 (-4.244564000000000041e-04+9.389090000000000597e-05j)
 (4.501374000000000044e-04+9.185770000000000653e-05j)
```

Note the "(),+-, e-04"

Comment: Many options [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) such as `fmt`.

Comment: with: fmt="%7.10f+%7.10f"
I have 0.0001760855+-0.0000927256 (note the +-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
complex_array = [complex(0.0001760855-0.0000927256j),
complex(-0.0002311308+0.0000122892j),
complex(0.0002447444+0.0000968709j),
complex(-0.0002038497-0.0002121365j),
complex(0.0001077393+0.0003059170j)]

np.savetxt('tmp.txt', complex_array, fmt='%.10f%+.10fj')
```

tmp.txt:

```
0.0001760855-0.0000927256j
-0.0002311308+0.0000122892j
0.0002447444+0.0000968709j
-0.0002038497-0.0002121365j
0.0001077393+0.0003059170j
```